How do you use Gomock with AWS SDK?
For example, when I use gomock to test code that uses DynamoDB, like this:
    mockDynamoDB := awsmock.NewMockDynamoDBAPI(ctrl)
    mockDynamoDBClient.EXPECT().PutItemWithContext(gomock.Any(),
       gomock.Any() // Here I should use a custom matcher for comparing PutItemInput
).Return(&dynamodb.PutItemOutput{...}, nil).Times(1)

   // do something which will internally call PutItemWithContext

To avoid using gomock.Any() everywhere, I think I should implement a matcher for PutItemInput, however it seems a bit difficult as the PutItemInput is complex with serialized Item map[string]*AttributeValue, I need to compare one by one like this but I don't like this implementation.
func (piim dynamodbPutItemInputEqualMatcher) Matches(x interface{}) bool {
    input, ok := x.(*dynamodb.PutItemInput)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    if input.TableName != nil && piim.expectedInput.TableName != nil && *input.TableName != *pie.expectedInput.TableName {
        return false
    }

    for attributeName, attributeValue := range input.Item {
        exptectedAttributeValue, ok := piim.expectedInput.Item[attributeName]
        if !ok {
            return false
        }

        if attributeValue.N != nil && exptectedAttributeValue.N != nil && *attributeValue.N != *exptectedAttributeValue.N {
            return false
        }
        if attributeValue.S != nil && exptectedAttributeValue.S != nil && *attributeValue.S != *exptectedAttributeValue.S {
            return false
        }
        if attributeValue.BOOL != nil && exptectedAttributeValue.BOOL != nil && *attributeValue.BOOL != *exptectedAttributeValue.BOOL {
            return false
        }
        if attributeValue.NULL != nil && exptectedAttributeValue.NULL != nil && *attributeValue.NULL != *exptectedAttributeValue.NULL {
            return false
        }

        if attributeValue.B != nil || attributeValue.NS != nil || attributeValue.SS != nil || attributeValue.BS != nil || attributeValue.L != nil || attributeValue.M != nil {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

Also DynamoDB has other APIs like GetItem, ScanPages, etc,. I need to implement custom matcher for every type of input struct.
Do we have a better way to use gomock with AWS? Thanks.
===========================================
I don't think my case is overusing mocking, my code is not just a simple wrapper of DynamoDB calls, it implements my own business logic, finally writes to DynamoDB if needed. There are several reasons why I want to isolate DynamoDB from my unit test.
(1) to use real DynamoDB for testing, I need to setup valid creds before running unit tests in Jenkins and keep maintaining the creds, besides that, the environment where unit tests are executed must have internet connection, this is pretty hard, sometime impossible.
(2) I just want to validate my business logic in unit tests. For example, the function needs to validate the input parameters first, when user input is invalid, return error immediately, unit test should cover that, and this is totally unrelated to DynamoDB. The test cases here are focusing on my business logic, whether the business logic works as expected when different inputs are feeded in, not to validate DynamoDB if it is reliable, so it is reasonable to assume that DynamoDB always behaves as expected in my unit tests.
(3) It is the scope/goal of integration test that test functionality when combine my business logic with real DynamoDB together, we already have synthetic tests for this, unit test is just unit test. If I use real DynamoDB in testing, in case DynamoDB experiences outage, or the connection between Jenkins and DynamoDB breaks, the UT fails, I don't want my UT to be affected like this kind of failures.

This seems to be an example of overusing mocks. You leak implementation details of your code into your test, and the test only works if you use the mock in exactly the way you've written your code, which makes refactoring impossible.
You don't test whether you're making the right calls to DynamoDB (for which you'll have to reimplement DynamoDB), but if you're doing the calls that you're doing - when they are wrong, you'll have to fix your tests too.
So what you want to do here is to just return the expected results to see if your code is working, and error out only when your mock is not sufficient and receives unexpected queries - which is a problem of your mock, not your code.
Your mock shouldn't and can't verify all parameters - that's impossible without either reimplementing DynamoDB or restricting the set of valid calls so heavily that only the current implementation is valid.

My code is not just a simple wrapper of DynamoDB calls, it implements my own business logic, finally writes to DynamoDB. There are several reasons why I want to isolate DynamoDB from my UT.

@codewarrior: Yes, I assumed that. You still want to test your own business logic, not that you write to DynamoDB exactly the way you do.

(1) to use real DynamoDB for testing, I need to setup valid creds when running test in Jenkins and keep maintaining the creds, besides that, the environment where tests are executed must have internet connection, this is pretty hard sometime impossible.

(2) I just want to validate my business logic. For example, the function needs to validate the input parameters first, when user input is invalid, return immediately, my UT should cover that, and this is totally unrelated to DynamoDB. The test cases here are focusing on my business logic, whether the business logic works as expected when different inputs are feeded in, not to validate DynamoDB if it is reliable, so it is reasonable to assume that DynamoDB always behaves as expected in my UTs.

(3) It is the scope/goal of integration test that test functionality when combine my business logic with real DynamoDB together, we already have synthetic tests for this, unit test is just unit test. If I use real DynamoDB in testing, in case DynamoDB experiences outage, or the connection between Jenkins and DynamoDB breaks, the UT fails, I don't want my UT to be affected like this kind of failure.

cf. (1): https://testing.googleblog.com/2024/02/increase-test-fidelity-by-avoiding-mocks.html “difficult to instantiate (e.g., it connects to an external server)”. I get it.
cf. (2): https://testing.googleblog.com/2018/06/testing-on-toilet-only-verify-relevant.html “only verify arguments that affect the correctness of the specific behavior”.
(3) is basically (1), or do I misunderstand?
